# How can I get a list of recent queries with parameter values, not names?

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am aware of some ways for seeing the recent queries for the current database, such as:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.text AS [Query], dest.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.dbid = DB_ID()
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

My problem is that the results aren't showing the *values* being passed to the `PROC`, but are instead showing the names of the parameters. I already know the name of the `PROC` and I have the script. I need to know what a particular ASP app is passing in.

For now I just have the `PROC` `INSERT`ing the param values into a logging table, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Are you logging the USER_ID when inserting? That way you can sort by what program or user inserted. Or maybe I didn't understand your question properly.

Comment: Typically with SQL Server you will want to use SQL Server profiler it to see what SQL is executed against the database. Since about 2008? you can also use SQL Server Extended Events.

Comment: @BertEvans I'll have to look into that. I was hoping for a query that would show me, but maybe there isn't one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom logging in the stored procedure. Whenever the stored procedure is invoked, log an entry into the log table with the passed in params.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, as per the last paragraph of the question.